# Secured Markdown in Django

Tags: django, markdown

Does anybody know is there any django app/lib which give secured Markdown or other markup language? Or there is no any way to give users to use Markdown in secured for my server way?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703678/a-safe-python-html-text-formatting-ala-textile/1703739#1703739

Answer (score 3):

An also great solution that isn't mentionned in the link indicated in the comments, is the use of markdown2.

If you like using [markdown2](http://code.google.com/p/python-markdown2/) ;)

And it has also a secure mode in order to avoid html/js/css execution, so it would fit your needs! :)

```
return Markdown(safe_mode="replace/escape/Boolean").convert(text)
```

You can use :

- replace : will replace the html by an horrible text :p
- escape : Will escape the html text (what I prefer)
- Boolean: if set to True, will use replace. Boolean is here for retro-compatibility